# How to call variadic functions in unmanaged code, from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, c++-cli

I have a varadic function like following signature

```
__declspec(dllexport) MyFunc(string format,...){ 
    //ProcessingData
}
```

Now I have these in C# code to call MyFunc

```
  [DllImport(@"MyDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "MyFunc")]
  public static extern int MyFunc(string format, params object[] pars);
```

In the code :

```
  var fm = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("is");
  MyFunc(200, fm.ToInt32());
```

Calling MyFunc cause to receive wrong parameters.
Any idea what to do about this ?

Comment: A variadic C function requires always at least one argument that lets it determine how many actual arguments are passed.  Like the format string for printf().  The odds that this function can operate correctly are zilch.  The *params* keyword is not a match, the undocumented `__arglist` is.  Compare to [wsprintf for example](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/wsprintf.html).

Comment: Thanks you are right!! I didn't know about __arglist

Comment: @HansPassant Your answer did it exactly as I wanted but now there is another problem with number of arguments. I made a more clear question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657270/how-to-call-varadic-c-function-with-unknown-number-of-arguments-from-c